# vpn site to site, remote site behind firewall

Tags: vpn, checkpoint

I am trying to connect several computers located in a remote site to our company network.  we have been given internet access but not a public ip address.  we can use addresses in the range 192.168.10.0/24

I would like to create a site to site vpn using a product like pfsense.  our company firewall is checkpoint firewall 1.

Can anybody give some assistance with this?

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Perhaps this should be moved to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

VPN device need to have public IPv4 address to have Azure S2S